# Populate drop down list with current user value as the selected drop down list option asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I would like to know the best approach on populating a drop down list with all database values, AND have the current value for a user be the selected index. I have the drop down list being populated with the database values, but I'm not sure on how you select. Thank you

Comment: it is webform or mvc view?

Comment: @Pathik I believe it's a webform

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I haven't tried anything yet. I have been thinking it out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the `DataSource` Property of the Dropdown control to the dataSource. The DataSource can be a List or any other kind of DataSource.
2. Set the `DataTextField` property, which represent the text, which is displayed for each item in the dropdown list.
3. Set the `DataValueField` property, which represent the Unique Value for each item in the dropdown list.
4. Call the `DataBind` method of the DropdownList.
5. To set the selected item, set the `SelectedIndex` property of the dropdown to the index which needs to be selected.

Following code snippet shows how it can be done..

```
private void LoadDropdown()
{
     dropdownList.DataSource = YourDataSource;
     dropdownList.DataTextField = "DisplayPropertyName";
     dropdownList.DataValueField = "ValuePropertyName";

     // Bind the data to the control.
     dropdownList.DataBind();

     // Set the default selected item, if desired.
     dropdownList.SelectedIndex = indexOfItemWhichShouldBeSelected;
}
```